Fetch proximity between two languages through Python
Input 1 - "English"
Input 2 - "French"
Expected Output - 46.9 (Based on this website - http://www.elinguistics.net/Compare_Languages.aspx)
Is there any Python library that supports such a language similarity request? There are plenty of options for checking similarity of two sentences, but what about that of two whole languages.
The website in the question is the best one I could find but I'm unable to use it through HTTP request. Selenium is not an option here either.

Looks like you just need to contact the primary author directly. http://www.elinguistics.net/contact.html#:~:text=If%20you%20need%20compiled/bulk%20or%20aggregated%20data%20from%20eLinguistics.net%20for%20your%20own%20research%2C%20feel%20free%20to%20ask%20through%20the%20contact%20form.

@bar9833625 yep, I've submitted a comment to the discussion, although not public yet.
